# make:auth() Login/Register not working

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.5

I am working with `Laravel 5.5`. I created login/register page with `make:auth` about 1 month ago and didn't change anything inside Laravel auth core files. 
I just register and, after that I want to login. Login page reloaded when I hit login button and don't give any error messages. I don't know what's wrong. This code worked during 1 month and from yesterday it doesn't work right.
I just attached my login/register files here.

**Auth Register Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller {

use RegistersUsers;

protected $redirectTo = '/home';

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'member_id' => 'required|string|integer|min:000000|max:999999',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}

protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'member_id' => $data['member_id'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

This is my **register.blade.php**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
   {{ csrf_field() }}
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('member_id') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="member_id" class="col-md-4 control-label">
        {{ Lang::get('all.info.member_id') }}
    </label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="member_id" type="number" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' class="form-control" name="member_id" value="{{ old('member_id') }}" required> 
        @if ($errors->has('member_id'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('member_id') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">
        {{ Lang::get('all.info.password') }}
    </label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required> 
        @if ($errors->has('password'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 control-label">
        {{ Lang::get('all.info.confirm_password') }}
    </label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>
    </div>
</div>

</form>
```

This is my **login.blade.php**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('scout_id') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
       <label for="scout_id" class="col-md-4 control-label">
          {{ Lang::get('all.login_p.scout_id') }}
       </label>

       <div class="col-md-6">
           <input id="member_id" type="number" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' class="form-control" name="member_id" value="{{ old('member_id') }}" required autofocus>

           @if ($errors->has('member_id'))
               <span class="help-block">
                   <strong>{{ $errors->first('member_id') }}</strong>
               </span>
           @endif
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">
            {{ Lang::get('all.login_p.password') }}
        </label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
           <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

           @if ($errors->has('password'))
              <span class="help-block">
                  <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
              </span>
           @endif
        </div>
     </div>

    <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                 {{ Lang::get('all.login') }}
             </button>
         </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: did you enable debug mode?

Comment: yeah, in .env file `APP_DEBUG=true` but i don't get any error. Page just reload , member_id field filleb with old value, but password is cleared. doesn't show up any error messages

Comment: that means your form has validation errors and you aren't showing/viewing  them on the page

Comment: its okay, main question is: why did i not see any problem like this till now? Because i didn't change anything :(

Comment: don't know,maybe you erased the translation for that lang, a coma in the wrong place, who knows

Comment: :D no, i didn't touch any translation, i just created new `all.php` for all of lang packages

Comment: you sad you didn't touch any transaction, then you say you added a all.php to the lang packages so that means you touched the translations

Comment: i mean, i didn't touch `auth.php` , `pagination.php`, `password.php`, `validation.php`. i just created `all.php` for my labels. main problem is why auth() not working. input error field are same. i didn't change it. these fields have to show error not my lang folder.

Comment: do a `var_dump($errors)` on your view and paste the result here

Comment: can your provide the `LoginController`? ... if you just registered, you would also be logged in at that point, btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not telling the `LoginController` that your 'email'/'username' field is not `email`. You have to tell it you want to use a different field.

**Username Customization**

> "By default, Laravel uses the `email` field for authentication. If you would like to customize this, you may define a `username` method on your `LoginController`:"

```
public function username()
{
    return 'member_id';
}
```

[Laravel 5.5 Docs - Authentication - Authentication Quickstart - Authenticating](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#included-authenticating)

Comment: okay i knew it. But it work during a long period without any error. It has to give any error if i don't use email, i think. This doesn't  make sense.

Comment: that `LoginController` as is, was not using that `member_id` it was using `email`

Comment: okay. Do you not think it has to any error for notice me 'undefined email'  or smth like this ? I'm junior. I want to know it :)

Comment: no you would just fail validation for the `email` field as you don't have one in your form and you didn't tell the `LoginController` to use a different field, so the validation will fail as `email` is empty on the request.

Comment: okay, man. Thanks for your reply, spent your time for solution :)

Answer (score 3):

did you use Auth::attempt(); ?

`Auth::attempt(['member_id' => $request->member_id, 'password' => $request->password]);`

Comment: yeah bro, i tried Auth::attempt and it worked. But make:auth is still not working. Thanks for try!